# GetSizeForItem not triggering

Tags: xamarin

I want to have different height for each cell in my UICollectionView. Therefore I am overriding the GetSizeForItem method in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout like this:

```
public class MyCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    public override CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //  TODO custom height logic 
        return new SizeF(100, 100);
    }
}
```

This is how I create the UICollectionView and use the custom delegate class:

```
var flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        {
            ItemSize = new SizeF(320, 80),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
            MinimumLineSpacing = 0,
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0,
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height - 100, 0, 0, 0)
        };

        var collectionView = new UICollectionView(UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame, flowLayout);
        collectionView.Delegate = new MyCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout();            

        collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(MyCollectionCell.Nib, MyCollectionCell.Key);
        var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(collectionView, MyCollectionCell.Key);
        collectionView.Source = source;
```

The problem is that the GetSizeForItem method never gets triggered. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Xamarin's forums [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/90565/#Comment_90565), it looks like you can't use `Delegate` and `Source` at the same time.